# Permanently set the security attributes for TFS directories

Tags: visual-studio, security, tfs

On our Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2013 Premium running as Admin:

- Whenever we take the latest code from TFS

[image]

- And things seems to be working fine

[image]

- Yes, we get a few conflicts. But they are all solved later

[image]

- We **always** get the directory access issues

[image]

- Because, the directories are read only

[image]

- We **always**, make directories readable

[image]

[image]

[image]

- And the errors are gone

[image]

We've a *little big* team, say if every developer spend 5 minutes solving this - the total wastage is

> 5 minutes * no. of developers

Is there a way to **permanently** set these kind of security attributes, so that every time we get the latest code - we've these attributes already set and no access issues are faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an issue of the account used by VS not having sufficient permissions to the local files used by TFS.

You can try to give the related permissions to the users.

**Update**

[image]

***uncheck Read-only***

[image]

***Give full control for all users.***

Comment: Can you please elaborate on permission. I mean specifically what permissions?

Comment: You can try this way -Go to the "Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces” mapping folder and gave all local users full control. Details see my update answer.

Comment: Looks logical, I'll try this and see if it works well.

Comment: Although, the errors are reduced. I still have the issue only for `Could not write lines to file obj\Debug\ProjectNameHere.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt Access to the path is denied`. Now, there is only **one** error only for this **one** file

Comment: Well, it's hard to narrow down the issue,  if it only occurs on one particular file. Maybe you can try to run your VS  as admin when try to get latest code from TFS . If this is not work, you can also unbind the file in source and rebind it again.

Comment: You mean exclude and then include the file? Btw, VS is already running in admin mode.

Comment: No, I mean the source control bindings. Just like the answer from *Joel* in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings

Comment: Still have error with that special file? Maybe you can first back up this file and using [tf destory command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control) which permanently delete, version-controlled files from Team Foundation version control.  Destroy this special file.Then add the files back to your project in source control.  Then try again.

Comment: However, destroy the file in TFS **this will break your source control history of this file**. Please think over carefully. If your team can stand for this issue, suggest you keep regardless of that file.