# Invalid source control bindings after moving code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I have a heap of C# solutions and projects organised underneath a single directory called Code. I needed to move that whole folder. Having done that, I was left with a few minor inconveniences, such as invalid recent project links in Visual Studio and invalid paths in IIS sites. Those things were easy fixes. Some of the solutions are source controlled in TFS and I found upon first load that the mappings were also broken. Again, that was a fairly straightforward fix by editing the workspace and manually updating the local folders.

However I am left with one final issue that I just can't seem to get past, and that is invalid source control bindings. For example I have a solution with 4 website projects in it. Of the 4, 3 have invalid bindings. I have tried using Change Source Control to unbind the invalid projects, then unload and reload the projects, but it doesn't do anything. In the Change Source Control screen the server bindings that are listed are very much valid, as in, they exist and I can browse to them in Source Control Explorer. It's doing my head in.

Does anyone have any other ideas for things to check, test, or try..?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your solution is already added to source control: File > Source Control > Add Solution to Source Control.

Usually unbinding and rebinding will fix it, you can try to rebind back to source control
In Visual Studio:

1. Open a solution with the problem
2. Choose the solution in Solution Explorer
3. **File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control**
4. Unbind any projects that are bound but not working correctly.
5. Bind all projects that are now unbound.

You can also reference this article about [HOW TO FIX TFS INVALID BINDING IN VISUAL STUDIO](https://nooblikeaboss.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/how-to-fix-tfs-invalid-binding-in-visual-studio/)

However, if rebinding doesn't work, you can try to edit the solution files directly, for more information please refer to **Jonathan Nixon's answer** in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128730/re-establish-tfs-source-control-bindings).